# MongoDB which pattern is optimal for storing?

Tags: mongodb

I have an app that tracks basketball data on a week by week basis. This data is manually entered in by a user, I also want to reference the data by the user who tracked this data and by which week it was tracked.

I am user `Mike` it is `Week 1` I track the game, should I save the data like this.

Collection: Players

```
{ playerName: 'Derrick Rose', trackedBy: 'Mike', week: 1, points: 20 }
```

Or

Collection: Players_Week_1

```
{ playerName: 'Derrick Rose', trackedBy: 'Mike', points: 20 }
```

The first makes the most sense and I am sure mongoDB was intended for this kind of use, as the collection grows there will be a lot of documents but thats what mongoDB is optimized for I guess.

So basically my question is when building an app, should the data given its a `Model` ie. `Player` it should always be a part of a `Collection`. Even though in some cases that model is broken up into weeks, created and associated to a particular user.

I am sorry if this is a silly question, but as I become more advanced I just want to be confident in how I think about mongoDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about how you are going to query that data. Breaking it up into separate weekly collections will make life very hard if say you want to retrieve *all* results for a single player in which case you will need to query each collection and combine results. Mongo has a limit on the size of a single document but collections can be very large. If you go with the approach 1 (`Players` collection) you can add an index on `playerName` and `week` to make searches faster.